# WildFly 15+ unable to start persistence unit

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, wildfly

Good day

I am porting an existing JSF 2.3 application from WildFly 14 to latest WildFly 17

Using mvn clean package works 100% with zero warnings.

When I try to deploy the war using a plethora of different methods, all of them fail when trying to setup the Hibernate persistence unit.

Here is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">     <!-- Model Version -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>     <!-- Application package information -->
    <groupId>com.comp</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>     
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>EDSNext</description>
    <url>http://comp.com</url>     
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>     <!-- mvn repositories -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss</id>
            <name>public-jboss</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net-maven2-SNAPSHOT-repository</id>
            <name>Java.net SNAPSHOT-Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net-maven2-repository</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>bintray-snapshot</id>
            <name>libs-snapshot</name>
            <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>bintray-deluan-maven</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://dl.bintray.com/deluan/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <!-- Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.5.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.9.SP02</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.9.SP02</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Runtime dependencies.  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TODO: Need to replace shiro and move to KeyCloak -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Text templating-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.28</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>     <!-- Build settings -->
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-maven</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>3.0</version>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The error I get in the server log is:

```
08:48:53,006 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.beans] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) HHH10005004: Stopping BeanContainer : org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl@7b81609b
08:48:53,010 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."edsnext.war#PostgresDS": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."edsnext.war#PostgresDS": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: PostgresDS] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@17.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@17.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:128)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.9.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:649)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@17.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:212)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: PostgresDS] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1016)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:942)
    at org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5-3@17.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@17.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:170)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1224)
    at java.base/java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1218)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(TreeMap.java:374)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:343)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:277)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionRegistry.findSQLFunction(SQLFunctionRegistry.java:45)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findSQLFunction(SessionFactoryHelper.java:385)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode.getDataType(IdentNode.java:366)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:157)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:1018)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:786)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:677)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries(NamedQueryRepository.java:157)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:574)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:321)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
    ... 11 more

08:48:53,023 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "edsnext.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"edsnext.war#PostgresDS\"" => "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: PostgresDS] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: PostgresDS] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
```

Any idea what is causing this?

EDIT: Added persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             version="2.1"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="PostgresDS" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/PostgresDS</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/edsdb"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="25"/>
            <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: You'll have to debug in `SQLFunctionRegistry.java:45` which function name is searched for (probably `null`) and go deeper the stack to see which HQL Query statement causes this.

Comment: Thanks will do, but is this then a regression in WildFly 15+ or is it intended?

Comment: This depends on your findings. Did you upgrade Hibernate either?

Comment: @Selaron Hibernate and all JEE jars gets updated with each new WildFly release. Haven't found the answer yet, still investigating.

Comment: Where is your Postgresql JDBC jar located?  It should be in the modules directory as you're using JNDI to access it.

Comment: How is your data source defined?

Comment: Can you find out the solution?